# Has StackOverflow got a flag for 'Do this for me' questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

This question was prompted by this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632394/convert-this-query-into-sql-procedure).

The user has asked the community to 'Convert this C# code to SQL stored proc' yet has shown no attempt at doing so. From my point of view they are just asking us to do it for them.

According to the comments on this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368677/what-is-the-right-flag-for-how-do-i-do-this-with-no-effort-shown), 'Too Broad' would be the right flag to go with however I don't believe StackOverflow provides that flag anymore.

Again, I wouldn't say this post is 'very low-quality' or 'Needs more focus' as the question does seem quite specific in what the user is asking.

In a case such as this where the user is asking SO to do something for them, as of 2020, what is the correct flag?

Comment: "Needs more focus" is the new "Too broad".

Comment: @honk Thanks for the answer, I was sure that at some point SO had a flag for 'Do this for me' however I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: No, there is no "do this for me flag". If the question is adequately scoped and informed, is useful and interesting, "do this for me" is entirely fine.

Comment: There used to be a tag "do-my-biddings-minion" but it got banned due to "be nice" policy.

Comment: @yivi Really, I thought with the guide lines of SO, if the user has made no attempt to do the problem themselves and simply says, in this case, 'Convert this for me'. Surely that is not adequate enough.

Comment: I never said it was. I said: _"if the question is adequately scoped and informed, is useful and interesting"_.

Comment: The linked post is not a question - it's a command. As it contains no single question mark I would close it as "Not a real question" or "Unclear what you are asking" if such reasons were available. It does not fit to SO no matter how much focus it has.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I can't seem to find a flag for 'Not a real question' under 'Should be closed', I am assuming that as honk said, this would be closed with a flag of 'Needs more focus'?

Comment: @JamesS these are historical reasons I sorely miss.

Comment: yivi did a great job with finding duplicate. See George Stocker's answer. It's the best you can get.